# Memory efficiency with HashMap in Android

Tags: android, memory-management, hashmap

When I first started learning about `HashMap`'s I wrote my companies in-house Android app with individual maps for each line item's properties. Line items are dynamic and have several properties with corresponding values.

Example (Not all Maps are included):

```java
// Preceding onCreate()
HashMap<Integer, Double> latMap;
HashMap<Integer, Double> lngMap;
HashMap<Integer, String> descMap;
// In onCreate()
latMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
lngMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double>();
descMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

LogCat (Structure: `{ItemNumber=Value, ItemNumber=Value}`):

```
-- latMap output --
{1=0.0, 2=0.0}
-- lngMap output --
{1=0.0, 2=0.0}
-- descMap output --
{1=NULL, 2=NULL}
```

---

Now I am testing only having 2 maps, the main `HashMap` contains the item numbers and a containing map which holds individual properties and values

Example:

```java
// Preceding onCreate()
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> testMapFull;
HashMap<String, String> testMapContent;
// In onCreate()
testMapFull = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();
testMapContent = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

LogCat (Structure: `{ItemNumber{Property=Value, Property=Value}}`):

```
{
    1={
        object_lat=0.0,
        object_lng=0.0,
        desc=NULL,
    },
    2={
        object_lat=0.0,
        object_lng=0.0,
        desc=NULL,
    }
}
```

My question: Is there a significant difference in memory efficiency, etc? Everything is currently working as is. And yes, I know that the 2 maps have to be better then several, but they would contain the same amount of information with less to instantiate.

Comment: If you only have a handful of those maps, we are talking about a few 1,000 bytes at most. If memory is really constrained, you could save some memory by using the overloaded constructors that specify the capacity and load factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you declare a custom class that will hold the whole information about the particular item?
It will allow you to reduce the `HashMap`'s number to 1.

```
public class Item {
    public double lat;
    public double lng;

    public String desc;
}

HashMap<Integer, Item> itemMap;
```

It requires much less memory because uses only one `HashMap` and allows to avoid [`Boxing/Unboxing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) operations that create unnecessary temporary objects.

Also you can reduce the number of `Boxing/Unboxing` operations even more by using [`SparseArray`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html) instead of `HashMap<Integer, ?>`

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't thought about this. Correct me if I am misunderstanding, in your example I would have to create a new instance of the `Item` class for each line item. In your opinion would this still hold true as to requiring much less memory? I will look into `SparseArray`, can't see any reason why I couldn't switch over.

Comment: yep, as I said only one `HashMap`(or `SparseArray`) is used and there is no boxing/unboxing

Answer (score 1):

Possible resolution based on the answer provided by @vmironov, it looks like I am going to switch from `HashMap` to `SparseArray` with an `Item` class holding all of the variables.

Here is a quick example of how I am setting this up, for future visitors:

```
SparseArray<Item> sparseTest;

// Create an instance of this class for each item
public class Item {
    public String desc;
}
int itemNumber = 1;

// Set item variables
Item item = new Item();
item.desc = "Test Description";

// Once all variables are set, put into SparseArray
sparseTest = new SparseArray<Item>();
sparseTest.put(itemNumber, item);

// My application requires this data to be stored in a JSONArray
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
JSONObject innerJo = new JSONObject();
JSONObject wrapperJo = new JSONObject();
try {
    innerJo.put("desc", sparseTest.get(itemNumber).desc);
    wrapperJo.put("" + itemNumber, innerJo);
    ja.put(wrapperJo);
} catch (JSONException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And finally the output:

```
[{"1":{"desc":"Test Description"}}]
```

Since my line items values can be changed or modified, this can simply be done by:

```
sparseTest.get(itemNumber).desc = "Description Test";
```